# HP 6735s Brightness hotkey problem; where is brightness panel?

Tags: 11.10, brightness, acpi

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop hp 6735s. The screen is often too dark and i want to make it brighter, although the hotkeys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> are not working.

**I have tried some things:**

- Firstly it appears that sometimes they are in fact working, after reboot they either work and continue to do so or they don't.
- I've read about a brightness applet; but where can i find or install it?
- I have tried some grub options; `acpi_osi=Linux and acpi_backlight=vendor` but nothing changes.
- I don't want to add another question but since it might be related: my laptop also gets quite hot, i'm having doubts whether ubuntu connects to the available sensors and cooling plans (or how does it work???); sensors (or psensor) only shows 2 sensors both named temp1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Paul

Comment: Said to say i finally had to move to windows XP (where brightness control works), set the brightness level when plugged in and on batteries, then reboot to ubuntu and found the same defaults working. Still no brightness control with the hotkeys or any slider....

Comment: One more update; i've flashed the bios to the newest version from HP website but it makes no difference.... Still no brightness control in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 (precise) on HP 6735s

I had the same problem - this is how I resolved it.

I flashed the bios - now the brightness buttons work.

Just a word of warning, the sound-mute button stopped working....sigh...oh well, you can't have it all :)